# Using regex OR with find to list and delete files

Tags: regex, linux, find

I have a folder with these files:

```
sample.jpg
sample.ods
sample.txt
sample.xlsx
```

Now, I need to find *and* remove files that end with either `.ods` or `.xlsx`.

To fish them out I initially use:

```
ls | grep -E "*.ods|*.xlsx"
```

This gives me:

```
sample.ods
sample.xlsx
```

Now, I don't want to parse `ls` so I use `find`:

```
find . -type f -regextype grep -regex '.*/*.ods\|*.xlsx' | wc -l
```

But that gives me the output of `1` while I expect to have `2` files before I extend the command to:

```
find . -type f -regextype grep -regex '.*/*.ods\|*.xlsx' | xargs -d"\n" rm
```

Which works but removes *only* the `.ods` file but not the `.xlsx` one.

What am I missing here?

I'm on `ubuntu 18.04` and my `find` version is `find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use regex here, just use -name and -or and so:

```
find . -type f -name "*.ods" -or -name "*.xlsx" -delete
```

Find files ending with either ods or xlsx and delete

If you really wanted to use regex, you could use the following:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex "(.*\.ods)|(.*\.xlsx)" -delete
```

Make sure that the expressions are in between brackets